# Деление на слоги по теории Бондарко

Tags: фонетика, фонетический-разбор

Помогите, пожалуйста, разделить слова "архитектор", "гигантский" по теории Л. В. Бондарко.

Мой вариант разбора:
архите-ктор, ги-гантский

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По Л. В. Бондарко:

- а–рхи–те–кторъ (ъ — придыхание);
- ги–га–нтский.

Не забывайте, что все слоги в теории Лии Васильевны Бондарко считаются открытыми (за некоторыми исключениями).